# How to run cage transform in python fu

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

I'd like to run the [cage tool/cage transform](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-cage.html) from a python script.

The Python Procedure Browser can't find any entries while searching for "cage", "warp", "transform" and similar.

Also `dir(pdb)` don't list procedures with *cage* inside the name.

Related:

- [GSOC10 Project](https://www.google-melange.com/archive/gsoc/2010/orgs/gimp/projects/michael_mure.html)
- [Git Repository of the cage tool](https://github.com/MichaelMure/Gimp-Cage-Tool)